# Is there any function like pandas.cut in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, bin

I have a data base of the following type:

```
My_Variable
20
2
3
13
4
5
31
```

I know in python if I want to bin this I simply do:

```
My_Table['Bin'] = pd.cut(My_Table['My_Variable'],[0, 5, 10, 20, 1000])
```

And the result I get is:

```
My_Variable Bin
20        (10, 20]
2         (0, 5]
3         (0, 5]
13        (10, 20]
4         (0, 5]
5         (0, 5]
31        (20, 1000]
```

Is there any function similar in SQL to do this? Or I have do it manually with something like this:

```
case
when 'My_Variable'<5 then '(0, 5]'
when ....
end as 'Bin'
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What variant of SQL are you looking at, Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a bin using a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when my_variable <= 5 then '(0-5]'
             when my_variable <= 10 then '(5-10]'
             when my_variable <= 20 then '(10-20]'
             when my_variable <= 1000 then '(20-1000]'
        end) as bin
from t;
```

Some databases might have more specialized functions, but this would be a mechanism that works regardless of database.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I posted as well at the top. I was wondering if there is something else other than do it by cases. Thank you for your answer!